# chrome.debugger.detach({tabId}) detachs not just the tab with tabId but all other tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that debugs some tabs at the same time using chrome.debugger api. When one of the debugged tabs is done, I detach the debugger from that tab using chrome.debugger.detach({tabId}). However, all other debugging tabs get detached as well, and cause the error `Error: Debugger is not attached to the tab with id: tabId.`. This is not what I expected and it does not follow what the [chrome document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/#method-detach) specifies. Can someone explain for me why is that or what wrong have I done?

Comment: https://crbug.com/1170381

Comment: @wOxxOm oh thanks a lot, a bug from Jan 26, 2021 but still not fixed